# How can I access Google's search engine results programmatically and get the first URL with Autohotkey?

Tags: automation, autohotkey

I want to access Google's search engine results programmatically and get the first URL with Autohotkey.

I can access google video search page but I don't know how can I parse the first video URL.

```
Send ^c
if !Html := UrlGet("https://www.google.com/search?tbm=vid&hl=en-TR&source=hp&biw=&bih=&q=%clipboard%") {
            MsgBox No data returned from Google.com
            return
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a [regex](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/RegEx-QuickRef.htm).

Add to your code:

```
RegExMatch(Html, "O)<h3 class=""r""><a href=""([^""]+)""", m)
MsgBox, % "The first result is: " m.1
```

You might want to further tailor the above regex pattern to your specific needs.